# Oracle Minus query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have problem with Oracle minus query. If my query is like this

```
 select col1 from 
(select '1' col1 from dual
union
select '2' col1 from dual )
minus
select col1 from 
(select '1' col1 from dual
 );
```

Result is as expected 2 . But If I put a Semicolon after Query 1 as below

```
select col1 from 
(select '1' col1 from dual
union
select '2' col1 from dual );
minus
select col1 from 
(select '1' col1 from dual
 );
```

Result is 1 .Can anybody explain me why Result is like this. I am using PL/SQL Developer

Comment: when you put a semi colon.  it means the query is completed. So your tool just executed your query only till that! Instead, When you select the entire query and then execute, you will just get a syntax error!

Comment: oracleUser:  then Query should result 1,2 why it resulting only 1.And it is not giving Sysntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put the semicolon after first select it means that the select is finished, there for you got two separated selects

`first select is:`

```
select col1 from 
(select '1' col1 from dual
union
select '2' col1 from dual );
```

and it returns `1 and 2`

`the second is:`

```
minus
select col1 from 
(select '1' col1 from dual
);
```

`minus` haven't got any meaning in this part but the select can run and it returns `1`

there for you just run your query from the second part and see `1` as your result.

Comment: Great. It actually ignores "minus" runs both statement in PL/SQL developer and gives results in two tabs.I missed result in first tab.